# Usage of "on" versus "in"

Tags: prepositions, usage

Thinking about how **on** and **in** are used:

we

> go **on** vacation ***but don't*** go **in** vacation
>   speak **on** a topic ***but don't*** speak **in** a topic
>   think **on** it, ***but don't*** think **in** it

and we

> fall **in** love, ***but not***, fall **on** love
>   drive **in** a car, ***but not***, drive **on** a car
>   speak **in** a language, ***but not***, speak **on** a language

but we also :

> fly **on** a plane ***and*** fly **in** a plane
>   ride **on** a bus ***and*** ride **in** a bus
>   sit **on** a chair ***and*** sit **in** a chair

**On** usually refers to being **in contact with the surface** of something, and **in** usually refers to being **surrounded by** something and so would be mutually exclusive, however the last three examples contradict this.

Except through repeated usage, is there a way to anticipate what the exceptions might be?

Comment: This sort of "on vs. in" issue has been done to death in several languages already...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> On usually refers to being in contact with the surface of something, and in usually refers to being surrounded by something and so would be mutually exclusive

Not really.

When you ride a mass-transit vehicle, you can stand up in it (at least when it's not moving).  So *on* makes sense here.  Especially buses - some might have standing room only.  You will both be *on* and *in* the bus.

The same thing with a chair - a chair with armrests and a high back will surround you on all sides, but you are also atop the seat, so both *in* and *on* apply, depending on the type of chair.  You wouldn't be *in* a barstool, but you'd definitely be *in* a recliner.

> Except through repeated usage, is there a way to anticipate what the exceptions might be?

Not really.  The "right" preposition with certain verbs and categories of nouns - especially certain nouns that don't refer to physical objects - is effectively arbitrary and needs to just be learned.

*Speaking in French* is a great example.  You can invent situations to help you remember - perhaps a person who isn't familiar with a foreign language feels "surrounded" by the words in some sense.

Some hints and patterns:

- An authority figure can put you *on* various states of freedom/grace - on vacation, on leave, on notice, on punishment, on administrative leave, etc.
- Topics of conversation or meaning are something one is *on*.
- Emotional states are something one is *in* - in love, in sadness, in madness, in good spirits, in ecstasy.

Comment: As I think has been mentioned before on ELL, vehicles are a little strange in that you're *on* a bicycle or motorcycle, *in* a car, but *on* a bus, ship, or airplane.

Comment: @stangdon, you are correct in/on does get asked from time to time, however, the real part of the question is about ways to approach this, which usually does't get asked, but hopefully will be beneficial for ell'ers

Comment: What about "It is on the inside"? You don't hear people saying "It is in the inside" even though it would make more sense.

Comment: If you mean touching an inside surface, *on the inside* is fine.  *In the inside* isn't used because you can just say *inside*.

Comment: Arbitrary? Then, even native speakers can't expect which preposition would be well collocated with a word **in some fixed expressions** they happen to meet? If really so, how come they're even easily able to find out an error or awkwardness in a fixed expression miswritten by someone they face at first time? Do even they have to learn them one by one, as well as non-native speakers do? Can't they creat a new idiomatic expression naturally?

Answer (score 1):

The preposition on is the most difficult of all English prepositions. The Longman Dictionary DCE distinguishes 30 uses in the entry "on, preposition". There is no handy rule for "on" and "in".

Answer (score 1):

You will remember each of them once you have used it a few time in different context.

Try to make a few examples on your own:

- I am on vacation
- He was on vacation last month.

Use it a few times in real-life context and it will pop up automatically next time you need to use it.