# On vs. In usage

Tags: grammar

Which is grammatically correct of the two?

- The CI proudly walked on their processional march.
- The CI proudly walked in their processional march.

Or are there any other preposition more appropriate for this?

Comment: Both are grammatically correct, depending on what you mean. Other prepositions that would be correct there are *to*, *from*, *with*, *for*, *behind*, as well as others. You need to make clear what you want your sentence to mean.

Comment: Can you clarify the context of this sentence?

Comment: This answer seems to be a duplicate of https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/76111/usage-of-on-versus-in

Answer (score -1):

I feel that **in** is more appropriate for this usage, but strictly speaking it depends on what one means as a "march" in this instance (and regardless both sentences feel...weird, to me as a native English speaker, mostly due to "processional march").

As a verb, to "march" is "to walk in a military manner with a regular measured tread".

As a noun, a "march" is either a) a rhythm that one would walk through, b) a group of people walking together (generally marching), or c) (more rarely) a route or path, that one would be marching along.

"In" here implies that the CI "proudly walked" as a part of a group (or if the CI is multiple individuals, they could be the entirety of the marching group) of marching individuals (Also, if this is the case, I would generally just call the processional march a "procession").

"On" here implies that the CI "proudly walked" along a processional route.

Comment: At the very least you're reading your own idiosyncrasies into *in* and *on*. There is no reference in the OP's sentence to a group. What if the CI was marching alone? The preposition here addresses the march, not the person (or people) marching.

Comment: @Robusto: As I said, it depends on the meaning of "march". A march can refer to a group. Merriam-Webster defines it as, "an organized procession of demonstrators who are supporting or protesting something", as well as "the distance covered within a specific period of time by marching", which I believe, generally match the working definitions I have provided. The first part of my answer indicates that I think that "march" here has the group meaning, due to the use of the adjective "processional", which matches the group definition, so I indicated that that was the most likely answer.

Comment: Also, I don't think I'm adding my idiosyncrasies at all. This is how I speak and am spoken to, as a native English speaker surrounded by mostly native English speakers. My dialect of English, if you will. That my experiences don't match up with yours is not surprising; English is spoken by hundreds of millions of people, on every continent on Earth. If you feel my answer was wrong, by all means, post an answer yourself.

Comment: I gave my answer in a comment to the OP's question. I felt, and still feel, that the question is unanswerable in its current form. Apparently you felt something along the same lines, but went ahead and answered anyway.