# Is sentence ‘half the grammar is wrote down on this book’ nonsense?

Tags: sentence-meaning

This is the definition of ‘grammar’

grammar: the **whole** system and structure of a language or of languages in general, usually taken as consisting of syntax and morphology (including inflections) and sometimes also phonology and semantics.

Is sentence ‘half the grammar is wrote down on this book’ nonsense?

Comment: Thank you for rewording this. For clarification, I'm assuming you are talking about writing a sentence related to what you have read.

Comment: @BreWoodsy Yes!

Answer (score 1):

It's still difficult to answer your question, but I'll try according to what I understand. I don't know what you mean by "nonsense;" but grammatically, it is incorrect.

Because you are speaking of information in the book, you would not use "**on** the book" you would use "**in** the book." Check this [link](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/76111/usage-of-on-versus-in#:%7E:text=On%20usually%20refers%20to%20being,last%20three%20examples%20contradict%20this.) out for other answers related to "on vs in."

Wondering about half vs half of? Here's information from Collins:

> 1 used in front of noun phrases
> Half or half of an amount or object is one of the two equal parts that together make up the whole amount or object.
> You use half or half of in front of a noun phrase beginning with a determiner. Half is more common.

> He had finished about half his drink.

> She is allowed to keep half of her tips.

Check this [link](https://depts.washington.edu/engl/askbetty/tenses.php) out for information on the verb tenses.

Alternative options to your sentence would include:

"Half [of] the grammar is written down in this book."

"Half [of] the grammar has been written down in this book."

"Half [of] the grammar was written in this book."